# Assigning a pointer to the structure with pointer to its field

Tags: c, embedded-linux, uart

What does `struct uart_omap_port *up = (struct uart_omap_port *)port` means?.

Is it similar to container_of macro?

Comment: Read about type casting - in particular of pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct uart_omap_port *up = (struct uart_omap_port *)port;
```

It means that you "port" pointer variable should be typecast to of type "struct uart_omap_port". This is not required in C as it would implicitly do the typecasting(if your port is of void*). This is not macro it just way(typecasting) the pointer with the different type.

**EDIT**

Code Snippet From Linux/drivers/tty/serial/omap-serial.c

```
static void serial_omap_enable_ms(struct uart_port *port) {
    .....
    struct uart_omap_port *up = to_uart_omap_port(port);
}


#define to_uart_omap_port(p)    ((container_of((p), struct uart_omap_port, port)))

#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({                    \
     const typeof(((type *)0)->member)*__mptr = (ptr);    \
     (type *)((char *)__mptr - offsetof(type, member)); })
```

This is the code which you have reffered. Yes,'to_uart_omap_port' is the MACRO
which internally uses 'container_of' and 'offsetof' MACRO.

This has been written to get the pointer 'up' which is of type 'struct uart_omap_port'
from the pointer 'port' of type 'struct uart_port'. This is bit complicated and you 
need to check how 'struct uart_port' and 'struct uart_omap_port' been declared.

Comment: It would only implicitly convert if `port` were `void *`

Comment: @mantosh.By referring omap-serial.c for (3.1)[3.10](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/serial/omap-serial.c?v=3.10) and for (3.4)in [3.4](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/serial/omap-serial.c?v=3.4),I could make out that this assignment is used in 3.4 kernel source code 'struct uart_omap_port *up = (struct uart_omap_port *)port;' instead of 'struct uart_omap_port *up = to_uart_omap_port(port)'.I am confused with that statements.Please clarify

Comment: @MantoshKumar:Then it seems both the statements are different right? But one more doubt.Where is that macro used in [3.4](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/serial/omap-serial.c?=3.4)?

Comment: @MantoshKumar:I m sorry.The link mentioned is not the correct one,bit of word mismatch.Please check out this [newlink](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/serial/omap-serial.c?v=3.4)

Comment: @MantoshKumar:I am sorry if i am disturbing you. I understand the difference between the two statements(Macro and the pointer type casting.Thanks for your clear explanation.But my new doubt is that, the usage of the macro(container_of) could'nt be seen in that kernel source of 3.4.

Comment: @Dino: Linux kernel is one of the world most happening and complex software project.So many data structure would be changed(some might be updated and might be removed). This is the reason you are not seeing the usage of a particular MACRO.You would have to understand the entire module source code and data structure to understand these all concepts.These MACRO and typecasting would be used
in all over the linux kernel project. Write small program using similar data structure and try to understand how they work. There is no short cut way to understand these concepts.